# Git Readability Problems on Windows

Tags: git

I'm using Git on Windows 10. And when I do a list of branches with `git branch -a` the resulting output isn't readable.

The master branch is in white. Ok, fine I can read that.
The active branch is green. Fine too, I can read that also.

But the inactive branches are red. And the default windows powershell window is blue. Red text on a blue background is NOT readable. And I want to change to one of the other branches.

I've tried changing the powershell window background to other colors. None of those are readable either with the red text of inactive branches.

Is there a way to change the output of Git so that inactive branches don't show up in red text?

Comment: Check out this answer, mainly the last part https://stackoverflow.com/a/37219999/3026886

Comment: You can tune the red.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your own colors in your `.gitconfig` file:

```
[color "branch"]
    current = green
    local = yellow
    remote = magenta
```

You can also use the `reverse` keyword to set the background color instead of setting the text color (example: `current = green reverse`)

For more options:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-color

Answer (score 2):

Turn off color of branch

```
git config --global color.branch false
```

> Git automatically colors most of its output, but there’s a master
>   switch if you don’t like this behavior. To turn off all Git’s colored
>   terminal output, do this:

```
git config --global color.ui false
```

If you want to be more specific about which commands are colored and how, Git provides verb-specific coloring settings. Each of these can be set to true, false, or always:

Learn more at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#_code_color_ui_code